# error in loading a custom class in sklearn pipeline using joblib

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I am trying to deploy an sklearn pipeline using FastApi
so first i saved my pipeline in a job lib file.

My pipeline looks like this:

```py
pipe = Pipeline([('encoder', MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns =['sg', 'al', 'su', 'rbc', 'pc', 'pcc', 'ba', 'htn', 'dm', 'cad', 'appet','pe', 'ane'] )),
                 ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                 ('model', lgb_model.best_estimator_)])
```

and my custom label encoder class looks like this:

```py
class MultiColumnLabelEncoder:
    def __init__(self,columns = None):
        self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self # not relevant here

    def transform(self,X):
        '''
        Transforms columns of X specified in self.columns using
        LabelEncoder(). If no columns specified, transforms all
        columns in X.
        '''
        output = X.copy()
        if self.columns is not None:
            for col in self.columns:
                output[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(output[col])
        else:
            for colname,col in output.iteritems():
                output[colname] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
        return output

    def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
        return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)
```

The columns attribute in the instantiation is for specifying the categorical variables then i tried loading it in my web app using the code below.

```py
import models.ml.classifier as clf
from fastapi import FastAPI
from joblib import load
from models.data import data_input
import pandas as pd
from utils import MultiColumnLabelEncoder
app = FastAPI(title="deployment", 
              description="API for machine learning project",
              version="1.0")


@app.on_event('startup')
def load_model():
    clf.model = load('models/ml/ckd_model.joblib')
```

I am getting the error below:

> raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}" attributeError: Can't get attribute 'MultiColumnLabelEncoder' on <module ' main ' from 'C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\ main .ple>
> [31mERROR.q0m: Application startup failed. Exiting.

Comment: Try to reduce the code as much as possible while the error is still reproducible and add the exact line where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the "main" module from anaconda home directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).